# How to add automatic scroll to next section on one page?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I want to add automatic scrolling between sections when the user scrolls down or up, after scrolling to half of the screen there is an automatic smooth transition to the next screen on the same page, after scrolling to half of that screen there should also be a smooth transition to the next section and so on.

Page code :

```
'use client'

import Image from 'next/image'

import About from './components/About'
import Lodge from './components/Lodge'
import AboutS from './components/AboutS'
import Reviews from './components/Reviews'
import Blog_h from './components/Blog_h'
import Contacts from './components/Contacts'

export default function Home() {

  return (
    <div className="">

      <section
        id="home"
        className="bg-local bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-cover bg-test-bg w-full h-[1080px]"
      >
        <div className="font-medium lg:text-[36px] md:text-[28px] sm:text-[24px] leading-normal text-white pt-[619px] pl-[80px]">
           Enjoy your time in Lux in the clouds
        </div>

        <Image className="pt-[30px] pl-[80px]"
          src="/images/portal360.svg"
          alt="Portal 360"
          width={1154}
          height={162}
        />
      </section>

      <section id="about">
        <About />
      </section>

      <section id="lodge">
        <Lodge />
      </section>

      <section id="abouts">
        <AboutS />
      </section>

      <section id="reviews">
        <Reviews />
      </section>

      <section id="ourblog">
        <Blog_h />
      </section>

      <section id="contacts">
        <Contacts />
      </section>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`sectionRefCallback` function is used as a ref callback to capture references of each section element. This ensures that the `sectionsRef.current` array always contains up-to-date references to all the sections.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const ScrollToNextSection = () => {
  const sectionsRef = useRef([]);
  const activeIndexRef = useRef(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const sections = sectionsRef.current;
    const activeIndex = activeIndexRef.current;

    const handleScroll = () => {
      const scrollPosition = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;

      if (scrollPosition >= sections[activeIndex].offsetTop + sections[activeIndex].offsetHeight) {
        scrollToNextSection();
      }
    };

    const scrollToNextSection = () => {
      if (activeIndex < sections.length - 1) {
        activeIndexRef.current = activeIndex + 1;
        sections[activeIndexRef.current].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  const sectionRefCallback = (section) => {
    if (section && !sectionsRef.current.includes(section)) {
      sectionsRef.current.push(section);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <section ref={sectionRefCallback}>Section 1</section>
      <section ref={sectionRefCallback}>Section 2</section>
      <section ref={sectionRefCallback}>Section 3</section>
    </>
  );
};

export default ScrollToNextSection;
```